# What dates to enter when purchasing travel insurance?

Tags: insurance, one-way

I'm getting quotes on travel insurance, specifically a one-way trip from Estonia to Australia (as we're moving there), and am a bit confused by what dates I should enter for the 'dates of cover'...

The obvious answer would be the travel dates (e.g. 1st Mar 2020 - 3rd Mar 2020), but would we still be covered if something happened before March and we had to cancel the trip?

Or should I enter dates like 20th Nov 2019 - 3rd Mar 2020 to cover everything from when we purchase the insurance until we arrive in Australia?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if any claims were denied on the basis that you were not actually "travelling" but relocating.  You should inspect the terms *very* carefully, especially if you're expecting this insurance to cover damage to the property you are moving.

Comment: Check the T&C carefully: some travel insurance explicitly excludes one-way trips & relocation to a new country.

Answer (score 5):

So I found this FAQ on https://www.travelinsuranz.com.au/page/FAQs:

> **What dates should I enter when getting a quote?**
>
> Your policy start date is the date that you leave your home in Australia. You will be covered under the cancellation section of your travel insurance from the moment you buy your policy until the date you leave Australia.
>
> The end date is the date that you arrive back to your home in Australia or your nominated expiry date whichever is the sooner.

That seems to answer my question (i.e. enter the dates of travel (e.g. 1st Mar 2020 - 3rd Mar 2020), and you're still covered for cancellation from the date of purchase). I assume the same is true of other insurance companies.

Answer (score 2):

Your travel is apt to begin in the departure date, but if you are delayed *en route*, it could end a day or two later. I'd choose a insurance end date a day or three after your planned arrival.